# Using Cygwin to zip individual files in a folder and zipping the entire folder

Tags: cygwin, 7zip, zip

i am trying to zip individual files in a folder. i can zip the directory using

```
tar -zcf <filename> <location to place the file after zipping>
```

please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this

```
tar acf foo.tar.gz README.txt bar.txt dog.txt
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/install/rtmpdump/rtmpdump-dist-static.sh)